# Android Contacts Access

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

```
Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] PROJECTION = new String[] 
        {
           Contacts._ID,
           Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
           Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        };
        String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "='1'";
    Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

here is a piece of code when i comment out last line it works and when i use it it gives the message the process (package name) is stopped unexpectedly.
u use permission of reading contacts in mainifiest file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the question is not clear . Yes you have to include the following permissions to read the contacts .

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: on line when cursor object is creating it give crash.